# Semigroup of a group and identiy

Tags: abstract-algebra, group-theory, semigroups

If $(G, *)$ is a group and $£$ is restriction of $*$ on subset $S$ of $G$. Is there some semi-group   $(S, £)$ such that identity of $(S, £)$ and $(G, *)$ are different.

Comment: What does "defined from a group" mean? This is incredibly vague.

Comment: Ok I'll edit it. It means if G is group with an operation * and S subset of G is a semigroup with same operation *. Will identity of (S, *) and (G, *)  will be same?

Answer (score -1, accepted):

Yes, if for some elements in $G$ we have $g\cdot h = h$ then necessarily $g =e$ ( cancellation law).

Comment: @orangekid Yes I get this proof